# Looping over array that includes promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

im building an angularjs application, were in 
`$scope.list` Arary items are stored, that are created by a specific ngResource factory. I delete some items on the fly by simply slicing them from the list.

```
$scope.list.splice(pos,1);
```

Later in code I iterate over existing elements and want to save them with :

```
for (var elem in $scope.list ){
     $scope.list[elem].$save();
 }
```

The Problem is that, if the list is empty i have an `$promise` in the `$scope.list` 
How should i process, so that the save is not called for the element that just have an promise?

Comment: If it's a promise for an array, use `$scope.list.then(function(list) { for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) …list[i]… });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by filtering your array and then save the items in the filtered array:

```
$scope.list
.filter(function (elem) {
  return typeof elem.then !== 'function';
})
.forEach(function (elem) {
  elem.$save();
});
```